# Why Does Electron Revolve around nucleus?

Tags: particle-physics

Actually why does electron revolve around nucleus. Considering Simple atom, hydrogen atom where a single electron revolves around the nucleus. It is said that the electrostatic force of attraction balances the centripetal force or similar to that. But, since we know that electron, as a negatively charged particle is attracted to the positively charged particle proton, why don't they collide each other, rather electron revolves around the proton(nucleus). What may be the reason behind this?

Comment: Did you try searching this site for this question first? I'm pretty sure there are loads of questions which refer to this exact same problem...

Comment: Downvoting a newcomer's question because it is a duplicate is just plain mean. Even I frequently miss duplicates and I've been a site member for four years! Downvoting is bad karma - downvote enough times and you could be reincarnated as a biologist.

Comment: Actually I searched over the site tons of times but I did not get the answers that I was looking for or similar like that.